# TimeSpan using a nullable date

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-2.0, nullable

How can I subtract two dates when one of them is nullable?

```
public static int NumberOfWeeksOnPlan(User user)
{
    DateTime? planStartDate = user.PlanStartDate; // user.PlanStartDate is: DateTime?

    TimeSpan weeksOnPlanSpan;

    if (planStartDate.HasValue)
        weeksOnPlanSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(planStartDate); // This line is the problem.

    return weeksOnPlanSpan == null ? 0 : weeksOnPlanSpan.Days / 7;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
weeksOnPlanSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(planStartDate.Value);
```

Answer (score 14):

To subtract two dates when zero, one or both of them is nullable *you just subtract them*. The subtraction operator does the right thing; there's no need for you to write all the logic yourself that is already in the subtraction operator.

```
TimeSpan? timeOnPlan = DateTime.Now - user.PlanStartDate;
return timeOnPlan == null ? 0 : timeOnPlan.Days / 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the nullable datetime as a normal datetime.

If you know it is not null, then the cast will work fine.